# How to config Apache to get error 502 Bad Gateway for testing?

Tags: apache-2.2, testing, configuration, 502-error

I'm developing a website with ajax allow many `queries` insert many many `row` to database in the same time. It's run ok on localhost, but when I deploy onto server (free Amazon server), it's often get error `502 Bad Gateway`. Now, I also want get `Error 502` on my Apache localhost for testing my code. So, how to config server? Thank for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/badurl
RewriteRule .* - [R=502]
```

All urls, matched pattern "^/badurl" will return 502 error.